# Can I test rule using Drools (KIE) Workbench?

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

I am new to Drools so my question could be obvious but I cannot find an answer.

I defined Data Model and Rule, built and deployed to my Drools server. Is any way to test it using Drools Workbench or I need to implement java client application or manually simulated call from web client like Postmen or SoapUI to Drools server? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I cannot test my rule from Drools Workbench and need to use either web client or application.

Comment: You could test it using Drools Workbench, Test Scenario. I also found out recently since I'm looking into Drools as well. This is an old post but hope it would help someone.